# Disconnect Internet connection Wi-Fi dongle (edimax 7811Un) raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I am using raspberry pi 3 and for Wi-Fi I am using Edimax 7811Un. Everything is working fine. But at situations I need to disconnect Wi-Fi connection. I don't want to down the interface by doing:

```
sudo ifdown wlan1
```

Because this will take the interface down completely. I want the wlan1 interface to be there but only disconnect the connection from current ssid.
I tried to use the command:

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan1 disconnect
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan1 error: connection refused
```

Please let me know if there any command to disconnect internet connection from command line with out taking the interface down

My /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf is as below

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
ssid="TestNw"
psk="testpwd@123"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

So my pi is connected to ssid: TestNw

Below is my ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:32:cd:70  
          inet addr:10.96.42.162  Bcast:10.96.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::a60c:c1f0:cb66:c0b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5559 errors:0 dropped:15 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:495585 (483.9 KiB)  TX bytes:214112 (209.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:175054 (170.9 KiB)  TX bytes:175054 (170.9 KiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:99:43:de  
          inet addr:192.168.43.122  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe99:43de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:34 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5366 (5.2 KiB)  TX bytes:36871 (36.0 KiB)
```

As you can see, two interfaces eth0 and wlan1 are up. Now I would like to disconnect the pi connection with ssid: TestNw

I want to do it with out getting the wlan1 interface down

Comment: Your question is unclear; what exactly do you mean by "disconnect"? What are the networks connected to? How are they configured? `dhcpcd --release interface` should release any DHCP lease on normal Raspbian.

Comment: I mean to disconnect from existing ssid.                                                 Below is my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file:                                                        ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
ssid="TestNw"
psk="testpwd@123"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}                                                                                                                         I would like to disconnect pi from the connection with ssid: TestNw

Comment: Where did you get the `wpa_cli -i wlan1 disconnect` command from? And the way to disconnect a interface is to take it down, normal procedure. Please edit your question with the wpa_supplicant.conf, it's unreadable in a comment.